# ASP.NET Core Web API - Third Party API not giving expected result

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webclient

In my ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I am given a third party API to consume and then return the account details. I am using WebClient.

api:

```
https://api.thirdpartycompany.com:2233/UserAccount/api/AccountDetail?accountNumber=112123412
```

Headers:

```
X-GivenID:Given2211
X-GivenName:Givenyou
X-GivenPassword:Given@llcool
```

Then JSON Result is shown below:

```
{
  "AccountName": "string",
  "CurrentBalance": 0,
  "AvailableBalance": 0,
  "Currency": "string"
}
```

So far, I have done this:

BalanceEnquiryResponse:

```
public class BalanceEnquiryResponse
{
    public string Response
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool IsSuccessful
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<BalanceList> AccountBalances
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

BalanceList:

```
public class BalanceList
{
    public string AccountNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public decimal CurrentBalance
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public decimal AvailableBalance
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Currency
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Then the service is shown below.

IDataService:

```
public interface IDataService
{
    BalanceEnquiryResponse GetAccountBalance(string accountNo);
}
```

```
public class DataService : IDataService
{
    private readonly ILogger<DataService> _logger;
    private readonly HttpClient _myClient;
    public DataService(ILogger<DataService> logger, HttpClient myClient)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _myClient = myClient;
        PrepareAPIHeaders(); // Actually apply the headers!
    }

    private void PrepareAPIHeaders()
    {
        _myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-GivenID", "Given2211");
        _myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-GivenName", "Givenyou");
        _myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-GivenPassword", "Given@llcool");
        _myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        _myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    }

    // If you want to use async API, you need to go async all the way.
    // So make this Method async, too!
    public async Task<BalanceEnquiryResponse> GetAccountBalance(string accountNo)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Accessing Own Account");
        var url = $"https://api.thirdpartycompany.com:2233/UserAccount/api/AccountDetail?accountNumber={accountNo}";

        var response = await _myClient.GetAsync(url);
        // vv Get your payload out of the Http Response.
        var responseResults = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<BalanceEnquiryResponse>();
        return responseResults;
    }
}
```

I tested the third party api with the headers on POOSTMAN:

> https://api.thirdpartycompany.com:2233/UserAccount/api/AccountDetail?accountNumber=112123412

[image: parameter]

[image: header]

and it gives me expected result. But from my code, when I tried to call **GetAccountBalance** from the code below and I supplied model.account_number:

```
public async Task<BaseResponse> FinalResult(RequestDto model)
{
    var response = new BaseResponse();
    try
    {
        //Check account Balance
        var accBalance = _dataAccess.GetAccountBalance(model.account_number);
        if (!accBalance.IsSuccessful)
        {
            response.response_code = "";
            response.response_description = "Could not fetch account for subscriber";
            return response;
        }
     }
}
```

I got this error in:

> response.response_description = "Could not fetch account for subscriber";

What am I doing wrongly, especially in **public class DataService** and how do I resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share how you are calling the API from postman?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - I have added the POSTMAN

Comment: The `URL` you are trying is it publicly accessible?

Answer (score 0):

It might just be that we talking about a GetCall but sometimes i had problems with headers which are set directly on the client layer. So i would try to set them on the request, instead of the client.

I wrote this without a editor so i could not test it.
But you should get the gist of what im trying to do

```cs
 public async Task<BalanceEnquiryResponse> GetAccountBalance(string accountNo)
 {
        _logger.LogInformation("Accessing Own Account");
        var url = $"https://api.thirdpartycompany.com:2233/UserAccount/api/AccountDetail?accountNumber={accountNo}";
       using(var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url))
       {
            //add headers to the request not the client
            PrepareAPIHeaders(request);
            var result = await _myClient.SendAsync(request);
            result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            
            /*Read response and parse it into an object and return*/
       }


        return null;
 }

    private void PrepareAPIHeaders(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        request.Headers.Add("X-GivenID", "Given2211");
        /*Add other Headers*/
    }
```

Comment: How do I add var responseResults = new BalanceEnquiryResponse() to the response in GetAccountBalance. Because I am having this error:    'Task<BalanceEnquiryResponse>' does not contain a definition for 'IsSuccessful' and no accessible extension method 'IsSuccessful'

Comment: sry about the delay im @ work. the result has also a content property so the handling should be the same as above